# How do I get currently active Request with Uber API

Tags: uber-api

I am writing an iOS App that uses the uber API.
I am trying to get the currently active request_id via the Uber API, however a GET request to /v1/requests does not work.
It seems from the docs, this endpoint is not available, however it would make sense that getting the currently active request_id is something very useful.
The User Activity endpoints v1.1 and v1.2 only return completed requests.
The user profile endpoint does not return any ride/request info.

Has anyone found a way how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

It's seem this is not currently possible to get the active request_id, unless you made the ride request from your app.

I want to check the progress of a active uber ride. This ride gets requested in the UBER app. Then I want my custom app to monitor that request_id's rides status ( ride started, location of car, and ride finished).

This does not seem possible with the current API.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to estimate a request for a real ride, or make a request for a real ride, you may need to use POST instead of GET according to Uber doc:

```
POST /v1/requests

POST /v1/requests/estimate
```

If you want to check the status of the request made, you can use GET:

```
GET /v1/requests/{request_id}
```

If you want to cancel your request made earlier, you can use DELETE:

```
DELETE /v1/requests/{request_id}
```

There are more like map and receipt on the Uber doc: https://developer.uber.com/v1/endpoints/

Or you can check the [UberKit](https://github.com/borischou/UberKit) which is a thin wrapper for the Uber APIs.